# Blocking Pdf Files From Direct Access Using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, blocking

This question have been on SO quite a few times, i have tried all the available options but still i am having hard time blocking a pdf file from direct access using absolute URL.

I using the following code inside .htaccess file which is in the same folder where pdf's are

```
Order Allow,Deny
  <FilesMatch "^[^.]+\.(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx|txt|rtf|ppt|pptx|xls|mp4|mov|mp3|mpg|mpeg)$">
   Deny from all
  </FilesMatch>
```

When i access the directory of the pdf files it shows me a 403 forbidden access but the moment i enter the absolute url of the pdf it starts rendering the pdf in the browser.

Directory Url http://thetutlage.com/demo/pdfReader/files

Pdf Url :- http://thetutlage.com/demo/pdfReader/files/tracemonkey.pdf

Any help will be great. I have also tried using a redirect rule if a file has .pdf extension but that doesn't seems to be working as well.

Comment: No, I get a 403 also when using the direct link to the pdf. Most likely it is your browser who has already cached the pdf file. Clear your cache or try another browser (always a good check)!

Comment: still the same thing it opens up the file inside browser i tried with chrome and firefox though it is not a browser issue

Comment: Tried on a different machine still it opens up the file

Comment: I still get a 403: forbidden. So there must be some other difference. Either a session exists for you but not for me, or it is an issue with IP ranges.

Comment: strange i have also tried deny from all but still it gives access to me, any idea on how to save files from direct access apart of what i have tried

Answer (score 2):

Works fine:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
<Files ~ "\.(gif|jpg|png|pdf)$">
Deny from all
</Files>
```