# Prevent download media pdf files in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have many pdf files in wordpress media. I want to stop downloading this pdf files. I want only display the pdf file but not download. How can i achieve this through htaccess. Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate to [Blocking Pdf Files From Direct Access Using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396033/blocking-pdf-files-from-direct-access-using-htaccess)

Try using

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
<Files ~ "\.(gif|jpg|png|pdf)$">
Deny from all
</Files>
```